# freebsd rc scripts and the env(1) shebang pattern do not work together

Tags: python, shell, freebsd, rc

I have a python script which I want to start using a rc(8) script in FreeBSD. The python script uses the `#!/usr/bin/env python2` pattern for portability purposes. (Different *nix's put interpreter binaries in different locations on the filesystem).

The FreeBSD rc scripts will not work with this.

Here is a script that sets up a test scenario that demonstrates this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create dummy python script which uses env for shebang.
cat << EOF > /usr/local/bin/foo
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
print("Hello foo")
EOF

# turn on executable bit
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/foo

# create FreeBSD rc script with command_interpreter specified.
cat << EOF > /usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo
#!/bin/sh
#
# PROVIDE: foo

. /etc/rc.subr

name="foo"
rcvar=foo_enable
command_interpreter="/usr/local/bin/python2.7"
command="/usr/local/bin/foo"

load_rc_config \$name
run_rc_command \$1
EOF

# turn on executable bit
chmod +x /usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo

# enable foo
echo "foo_enable=\"YES\"" >> /etc/rc.conf
```

Here follows a console log demonstrating the behaviour when executing the rc script directly. Note this works, but emits a warning.

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo start
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo: WARNING: $command_interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2 != python2
Starting foo.
Hello foo
#
```

Here follows a console log demonstrating the behaviour when executing the rc script using the service(8) command. This fails completely.

```
# service foo start
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo: WARNING: $command_interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2 != python2
Starting foo.
env: python2: No such file or directory
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo: WARNING: failed to start foo
#
```

Why does the `service foo start` fail?

Why does rc warn about the interpreter? Why does it not use the interpreter as specified in the `command_interpreter` variable?

Comment: I suspect the value of `$PATH` is different when `rc` runs, and so it can't find `python2`.

Answer (score 1):

*Self answered my question, but I'm hoping someone else will give a better answer for posterity*

The reason why env(1) does not work is because it expects an environment in the first place, but rc scripts run before the environment is set up. Hence it fails. It seems that the popular env shebang pattern is actually an anti-pattern.

I do not have a cogent answer for the `command_interpreter` warning.

Comment: Does the `ps`/etc. output for your script say `python` or `/usr/local/bin/python2`? I'm betting it says `python` and that mismatch is the cause of the `command_interpreter` warning. But that's entirely a wild guess.

Comment: I had the same error message as the op. @EtanReisner guess was spot on. My interpreter was "/usr/local/bin/python" but the shebang line in my script was "/usr/bin/env python" and that triggered the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The command interpreter warning is generated by the `_find_processes()` function in `/usr/src/etc/rc.subr`.

The reason that it does that is because a service written in an interpreted language is found in `ps` output by the *name of the interpreter*.